# ¿Como le doy color a una grafica de barras en R estudio sin que se duplique la información?

Tags: r, rstudio

Hola amigos tengo un df en el cual tengo investigadores y sus areas.
Al momento de graficarlos me aparecen grises por lo cual le agrego color con "fill" pero se me duplica la información de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿hay alguna manera de que solo me aparezca el color a la derecha y las etiquetas del eje x no aparezcan?
Este es mi codigo

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = linea1, fill = linea1))+
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`theme()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) para configurar mucho del aspecto del gráfico:

```
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl=factor(cyl)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]